# Is TRIM Supported for RAID0 in Intel Matrix RAID in Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, ssd, raid, mdadm

It appears that TRIM is supported for RAID0 arrays with mdraid in Ubuntu 14.04.

Intel now supports TRIM to Intel Matrix RAID (RSTe) RAID0 as of series 7 chipsets (and Intel's Windows driver).

Ubuntu 14.04 supports Intel Matrix RAID through mdraid.

So, given all of the above, can anyone confirm if TRIM is supported in Ubuntu 14.04 to a RAID0 set created through Intel Matrix RAID?

Thanks,
--H

Answer (score 0):

TRIM support was added to the device-mapper driver at some point ( that's what `dmraid` uses ), but I don't recall if it was in 14.04.  15.04 now uses `mdadm` to support intel fakeraids ( thanks to a lot of code contributed by Intel ), and I'm fairly certain that does.

Comment: Does mdraid in 14.04 LTS have the same improvements from Intel that you mention are in 15.04?